# Delay while starting one Activity from another

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two `Activities` named `LoginActivity` and `RegistrationActivity`. I am starting `RegistrationActivity` from `LoginActivity` on click of a button using `Intent`. But the problem is there is a **delay of 2 to 3 secs** to load the `RegistrationActivity`. What can be the problem ?

`LoginActivity`:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.loginLayout);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerText);
        email = (AppCompatEditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
        password = (AppCompatEditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginSubmit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(listener);

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeScaleUpAnimation(view, 0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
                ActivityCompat.startActivity(LoginActivity.this,
                        intent, options.toBundle());
            }
        });
    }
```

`RegistrationActivity` :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setup();
    new getLatLongAsync().execute();
}

private class getLatLongAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(RegistrationActivity.this)
                // The next two lines tell the new client that “this” current class will handle connection stuff
                .addConnectionCallbacks(RegistrationActivity.this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(RegistrationActivity.this)
                //fourth line adds the LocationServices API endpoint from GooglePlayServices
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

`getLatLong()` to get Latitude and Longitude:

```
private void getLatLong() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                // The next two lines tell the new client that “this” current class will handle connection stuff
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                //fourth line adds the LocationServices API endpoint from GooglePlayServices
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
    }
```

Comment: may be due to animation it is getting delay.check to try this only see if getting delay or not,  Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: I tried without animation. same result.

Comment: please call getLatLong(); inside AsyncTask or Thread. Calling function getLatLong(); may be delaying the load.

Comment: Can you share the code for getLatLong() method.

Comment: Can you give me an example of using AsyncTask in such scenario @Sanil

Comment: I think the problem is with your device. Try use other device

Comment: updated the question @hsm59

Comment: Other apps are running perfectly on this device @NguyễnTrungHiếu

Comment: Hi @Hiren please check my answer with updated code. AsyncTask calling is mentioned here..

Comment: Try hide   setup() and getLatLong(); in RegistrationActivity.class

Comment: updated code please check

Comment: I tried hiding `getLatLong()` but still delay is there @NguyễnTrungHiếu

Answer (score 1):

RegistrationActivity : updated code

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
            setup();
            //calling asynctask..
            new getLatLongAsync().execute();
        }

        private void setup() {
            layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.registerLayout);
            language = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.lang);
            email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regEmail);
            password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regPassword);
            nickname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regNickname);
            username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regUsername);
            dob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regDOB);
            submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regSubmit);
            prefs = new SecurePreferences(this);
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
            language.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
            submit.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

            languages = new ArrayList<>();
            languages.add("Select Language");
            languages.add("English");
            languages.add("Tamil");
            languages.add("Malayalam");

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, languages);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            language.setAdapter(adapter);
        }


     class getLatLongAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


              getLatLong();


                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
            }
        }

private void getLatLong() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                // The next two lines tell the new client that “this” current class will handle connection stuff
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                //fourth line adds the LocationServices API endpoint from GooglePlayServices
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
    }
```

Comment: mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this) should call onCreate.

Comment: This is not working for me. Application is getting crashed due to `NullPointerException`

Comment: I rectified the problem. But still there is a delay in starting the Activity.

Comment: @Hiren try calling setup() function inside AysncTask instead onCreate

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are trying to load lots of thing on `onCreate` method. Due to that your activity is taking time for creation.

**Follow [activity life cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)**

For your case put all `setup()` and your asyntask on onStart or any other proper method.

Thank you so much.

Comment: can you please update your code into this question ?

Comment: still your `GoogleApiClient` class is intialized onStart put it on onCreate method.. update your `LoginActivity` also ..

Comment: there is no change in `LoginActivity`

Comment: taking same time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151053/discussion-between-rujul-gandhi-and-hiren).